# Convert currency of the store but keep the default billing currency

Tags: magento-1.9

We would like to have a currency switcher that doesn't affect the billing currency.

As far as I understand with the default Magento currency switcher the customer will also be billed in the selected currency (correct me if I'm wrong), but we don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on payment method.

Some methods such as Ebizmarts_SagepaySuite will ask to charge in BASE currency or Store currency.

Base currency being the default currency of the store and store currency being the currency used to checkout.

This is because a standard bank account is in one currency only and you would require an additional account for that currency.